# How to pass Linear Combination of Columns to Aggregation functions in Pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

How to translate this sql part to equivalent Pyspark syntx :

```
Select sum(a*(1-b)) from MTABLE group by (a,b)
```

I tried creating a function that accepts two arg and returns x*(1-y) but can't pass that as sum argument

```
  df.groupby('a','b'

 .agg(sum(q1_sum1_udf('a','b'))).show()



def q1_sum1(x,y): 
     return int(x)*(int(y)-1)
```

I know this is possible in scala but couldn't find the same in pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without a UDF as the calculation is straightforward.

```
df = spark.sql("select * from yourtable")
result = df.groupBy(df.a,df.b) \ 
           .sum(df.a*(1-df.b))
result.show()
```

Edit:
Using a UDF. Define a function (lambda function shown here, but the way to define any other function is the same) and use the function with the previously defined name and pass the required arguments.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
#Define and register a function
f_sum = func.udf(lambda a,b:a*(1-b))
result = df.groupBy(df.a,df.b).select(f_sum(df.a,df.b))
result.show()
```

Comment: with this I get NameError: name 'a' is not defined or NameError: name 'b' is not defined

Comment: did you try the latest version? it has been edited a minute ago

Comment: yes thanks and I had to write them as capitals to work , I'm new to all these and I was trying by putting ' ' around the names